# Why does WebSphere create duplicate EJB environment entries?

Tags: ejb, websphere

I specified a String resource in an EJB with the `@Resource` annotation. The EJB is packaged within an EJB module. The ejb.jar has an ejb-jar.xml which specifies a default value for the String resource. The ejb.jar is packaged in an ear archive together with a web module.

When the ear is deployed to WebSphere, the *Environment entries for EJB modules* section shows **three** EJB entries:

1. The String resource I mapped for the ejb module;
2. The String resource I mapped for the ejb module, only this time it is called `EJB_fully_qualified_name/resource_name`;
3. The same fully qualified name of the resource but now mapped for the web module.

Unless I provide a default value for all the variants above the resource is not injected. If I add an ejb-jar.xml to the web module, WebSphere displays **four**  entries (one simple name and one fully qualified name of the resource per module). Is this a WebSphere quirk or am I doing something wrong? I am using WebSphere 8.5.5.3 in a cluster environment.

Here is the bean:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ConfigSingleton { 
    @Resource
    private String serviceLookup;
}
```

Here is the ejb-jar.xml:

```
<ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
            <session>
                <ejb-name>ConfigSingleton</ejb-name>    
                <env-entry>
                    <env-entry-name>serviceLookup</env-entry-name>
                    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                    <env-entry-value>value</env-entry-value>
                </env-entry>                
            </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: Please add your EJB fragment with resource, and your ejb-jar.xml fragment, that defines resource. Probably resource ref names are different thats why you are seeing 2. Regarding web module - check if your ejb.jar is not added wrongly also to the `WEB-INF/lib`, it should only be added at the ear level.

Comment: The web module did have the ejb module in its WEB-INF/lib - I removed it in the new build but WebSphere still displays the ejb entry for the web module. As for mapping, I did it exatly as [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/env_entry/env_entry.html).

Comment: Maybe you didn't redeploy? Add name to the `@Resource(name="myRef") and also use same `myRef` name in ejb-jar.xml. It would be much easier if you would provide code fragmets, instead of pointing to third party page.

Comment: @Gas Added examples. Not only I redeployed but reinstalled the entire app.

Comment: I see that Tracy has explained it already for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined 2 completely different resources; either may be looked up.

Per the Java EE specifications, when you don't use the 'name' attribute of the `@Resource` annotation a default name is provided for you, which is the fully qualified class name where the annotation exists followed by the JavaBeans property name (which is basically either the name of the field, or the name of the method with 'set' removed and the next character in lowercase).  The javadoc for the `@Resource` annotation is a little misleading as it just says the default is the field name; but does not clarify exactly what the field name is; it is in fact the class name followed by the field name, much like you would see if you printed out the `java.lang.reflect.Field` that would represent it.

When combining annotations and XML, the XML overrides the annotation only when the 'name' matches. In the sample provided, the names do not match, so you actually have 2 different resources.

If you want your `<env-entry>` in XML to override the `@Resource` annotation, so that you can inject a value, then you either need to change your annotation to look like this:

```
@Resource(name="serviceLookup")
```

Or change the `<env-entry-name>` to the fully qualified class name / serviceLookup.

Also, when the EJB module is included in a WAR modules things get a bit more complicated. Not the 'name' aspect, but where you can provide the value. In addition to providing a value in `ejb-jar.xml`, WebSphere also allows you to provide a value in `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`.  However, when the EJB modules is in a WAR, then it may also be provided in `ibm-web-bnd.xml`... since all of the resources for all of the EJBs are visible in the `java:comp/env` name space for the entire WAR module.  So, in the sample, you are getting two different names because of the defaults, and what appears to be two additional copies which are really just provided in case you want to override the values in `ibm-web-bnd.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing here is the different JNDI namespaces:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html

The resource value can be accessed from within the EJB module using the original name, but if it needs to be accessed from another module within the same application, it should give a JNDI path qualified by the module name, to ensure uniqueness (and traceability), and so on for other applications, and the global namespace.